# "X and Y are the length(s) of A and B, respectively": should length be plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In the sentence:

> X and Y are the **lengths** of A and B, respectively.

The intended meaning is that:

- X is the length of A
- Y is the length of B

Should *length* be used with the plural or the singular form?

Comment: X is a length; Y is a length; two lengths are being discussed. Plural.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thanks I wasn't sure whether the use of "respectively" would change that.

Comment: Respectively is only used with plurals. John, Jim, and Mary are captain, secretary, and coach, respectively, of the tennis club.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we compare this with a sentence like "Pen and pencil are the tools of the trade" tools is used in plural form and not singular form. Similarly I would consider "lengths" as the correct word.